# Simulate real mouse click in React

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to simulate a *real* mouse click in React. One that will cause any input with focus to receive the usual subsequent events (e.g. change, blur, etc).

I'm using the following, but the event flow is different from a real mouse click (my simulated click doesn't result in inputs with focus being blurred, for example):

```
const mouseClickEvents = ['mousedown']; //, 'click', 'mouseup'];
function simulateClick(element){
  mouseClickEvents.forEach(mouseEventType =>
    element.dispatchEvent(
      new MouseEvent(mouseEventType, {
        view: window,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        buttons: 1
      })
    )
  );
}

class C1 extends Component {
. . .
onMouseDown(e) {
  // simulate click on C2
  if (myConditionForSimulatingClick) {
    simulateClick(document.getElementsByClassName('c2')[0]);
    return;
  }
  . . .
}
. . .
}
```

If an input on some component has focus and I really click on C2 (which has no click handler), the input recieves change and blur events.

But, if same input has focus and I click on C1, the simulated event makes it through to C1, but nothing else happens (the input doesn't receive any events until I actually click somewhere else in the app). This is what I need: the element with focus needs to be changed and blurred even when a simulated click has been performed. Is this possible?

I have tried stopping propagation and preventing default for the C1 mousedown event, but neither (even together) change anything.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Set focus first, then the click?

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane unfortunately no, does nothing.